# Customer Details page is not redirecting properly. Its not appending "Id" input parameter after the ActionName

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to show the Customer Details after clicking on "Details" ActionLink by his/her ID. But the problem is whenever I click on "Details" ActionLink  from the CustomerController it's only redirecting `"Customers/Details/"` without appending Customers Id after the link `("Customer/Details/Id")`

I already tried MVC Attribute Routing for it but not working.

ActionResult Details Method in Index.cshtml from Customer Controller :

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var customers = context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    if (customers == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        return View(customers);
    }
}
```

Index View of Customer Controller :

```
@foreach (var cust in Model)
{
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(cust.Name, "Details", "Customer")
        </td>
    </tr>
```

> Error :
>   Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'Vidly.Controllers.CustomerController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'Vidly.Controllers.CustomerController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the ID as the third parameter so a correct link can be rendered.

```
@Html.ActionLink(cust.Name, "Details", new { id= cust.CustomerId })
```

Comment: You mean like this : 
@Html.ActionLink(cust.Name, "Details",new { id = cust.Id, controller = "Customer"})

Comment: @rishav I am pretty sure if both views are generated by the same controller, you don't need to specify the name of the controller because MVC will default it to the current on.